# Growable Lists in the Dart Typed Data Library

Tags: dart

I am trying to work with the lists provided in the Dart Typed Data library.

I need to create a list of unsigned 16 bit numbers, but I don't know how many numbers I'll need to put into the list up front.

The [API page for the Uint16List](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_typed_data/Uint16List.html) says there is a constructor:

> factory Uint16List(int length)
>
> > Creates a list of the given length. The list is a fixed-length list if length is provided, *and an empty growable list if length is omitted*.

(My emphasis added.)

However, the length parameter is not optional and trying to construct a Uint16List without providing a length parameter results in an error.

Is there a way to create a growable Uint16List (and any of the other lists in the Dart Typed Data library)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an error in the documentation. That description is inherited from List and does not apply to Uint16List.

If you look at the source code documentation for Uint16List, you will see the following:

```
/**
 * A fixed-length list of 16-bit unsigned integers that is viewable as a
 * [TypedData]. For long lists, this implementation can be considerably
 * more space- and time-efficient than the default [List] implementation.
 */
```

And for the constructor:

```
/**
* Creates a [Uint16List] of the specified length (in elements), all
* of whose elements are initially zero.
*/
```

All the other lists in TypedData  are fixed length as well.

Comment: I had hoped the Dart library docs would be accurate and complete - silly me! I may report a bug for this.